# redirect to a page programmatically in react-router 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using **react-router-2**. I want to redirect to a page programmatically after successful login or after some action performed.

My route file is like this(**routes.js**)

```
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
       <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
       <Route path="/login" component={Login} onEnter={redirectToDashboard}/>
       <Route path="dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={redirectToLogin}/>
   </Route>
```

**onEnter** hooks

```
function redirectToLogin(nextState, replace) {
    // Perform some authentication check
    if (!loggedIn) {
        replace({
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { nextPathname: nextState.location.pathname }
        });
    }
}

function redirectToDashboard(nextState, replace) {
  // Perform some check if already authenticated 
    if (loggedIn) {
        replace('/dashboard')
    }
}
```

I want to redirect to **Dashboard** `component` from **Login** `component` after successful login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To redirect you can use `router` object from context. You have to declare  context types in your component (component from which you make redirection). More about context [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html)

ES6/7 syntax:

```
static contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
}
```

Now you have access to router object and you can make redirection:

```
this.context.router.push('/dashboard');
```

Comment: Usage of this.context is deprecated