# ReactJS form submit this.props.history.push('/downloads') not linking through to the new page

Tags: reactjs, django, forms, push, history

I am trying to Push to a new page once a user has filled out a form using this.props.history.push inside the function below.

```
  handleSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault()
    try {
      const res = await newEnquiry(this.state.formData)
      this.props.history.push('/downloads')
      console.log(res)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response.data)
    }
  }
```

The ReactJS form is working fine on the /contacts page, and submits information to my Django back-end so I know it's working OK, however I cannot get the redirect to work and it's giving me this error message.

[image]

`<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>` is inside my form tag and that's working fine so I am pretty sure it's not a problem with my form.

Api.js

```
const baseUrl = '/api'

export const newEnquiry = formData => {
  return axios.post(`${baseUrl}/enquiries/`, formData)
}
```

Views.py

```
class EnquiryListView(APIView):

    def get(self, _request):
        enquiries = Enquiries.objects.all() 
        serialized_enquiries = EnquirySerializer(enquiries, many=True)
        return Response(serialized_enquiries.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post(self, request):
        created_enquiry = EnquirySerializer(data=request.data)
        if created_enquiry.is_valid():
          created_enquiry.save()
          return Response(created_enquiry.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(created_enquiry.errors)
```

serializers.py

```
class EnquirySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      class Meta:
        model = Enquiries
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case of this problem, when the error fires off, it is unable to read the `err.response.data` property. If there was no error, it would redirect you. In your Django app, check what the `error handler` is suppose to return.

Quick review of try/catch.

```js
try {
 // if everything passes, run this block
} catch (err) {
 // if something goes wrong, run this block
}
```

In this case, be sure to check what your full error is. It might be a `404` or something totally unexpected.

Comment: Thanks Nano. I can see the submitted data in Django app, so it has successfully Put that information. Even with this happening it's not redirecting.

Comment: Could you paste the code of the Django app for this particular route? For sure something has went wrong because JavaScript doesn't give an error for no reason. .

Comment: Thanks, I've added my code into the main code at the top of the page. Is this what you required?

Comment: When you get the error in React. What error do you get in the console? Replace `err.response.data` with just `err` so we can see full picture. If `.data` is unavailable, it might be 404 or something similar.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
    at Form.handleSubmit (Form.js:30)

Comment: Is Form.js the one linked inside of ReactRouterDOM? Like `<Route path="/fif" component={Form} />`? If not, then you would need to pass it in via props, since you are using class-based components

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure how I would do that. What do you mean by linked inside of ReactRouterDom? My App.js page has this installed import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom' so I can't workout what edit I would need to make to the code to pass this down. Can you help?

Comment: Could you add App.js which your <Route> components shown, so I can see your component/routes structure?

Comment: import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom' -- does this help?

Comment: Sorry for the long wait. I created a example GitHub gist https://gist.github.com/nanoproductions/9f422e7b6cc00282fce57b758cbcd6ed. Feel free to explore it and learn it of what's going on.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I don't understand based on your GitHub gist.

Comment: Do you have a git repo? I need the component App.js so I can see your route structure, and give you specific examples.

Comment: I managed to fix it by using the                 <Link to="/thankyou">
                  <button type="submit" className="button button-form">Submit</button>
                </Link> outside of the submit button. I know it's not the correct way, but it's working. Thank you for all your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: You could try <Redirect /> component. Check this thread out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43837212/this-props-history-push-works-in-some-components-and-not-others

Comment: Thank you Nano, much appreciated. The <Link> idea I tried earlier didn't quite work, as it doesn't submit my data into the backend. Here's a link to the up to date repo: https://github.com/atkinsl88/Park-House-SEI-Project-004 Thanks again, and sorry for the delay. Enquiries is where my form is (Form) and then my main project is in the 'project' folder.

Comment: Here is what you should do now. **Contact.js** `<Twocolform history={this.props.history} />` Then in Twocolform you iwll get access to history!

Comment: Thank you, that's fixed things. Really appreciate your help.